# More latency using VLC than java browser plugin reading a video streaming

Tags: java, vlc-media-player, streaming, plugins, latency

I am trying to see a video streaming in my PC from a mobile phone camera using Android and IP Webcam and I am able to do it but I have a problem with VLC.

Runs correctly using VLC and java browser plugin but using VLC have more latency than using java browser plugin and I believe than it would be the opposite. Java is not good to use in a real time applications but in this case runs faster in the browser than in VLC.

I have tried to change the default configuration of VLC (disabling buffering...) but always runs faster in the browser than in VLC.

Can you give me a solution or a reason than explains this behavior?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English :)